# export blade view to excel or word

Tags: laravel, reporting-services, laravel-blade

Is there a way to export blade view to word or excel as it is beside Maatwebsite/Excel and PHPword. my View contains Images,Tables and Paragraphs.
 I've searched a lot but couldn't find any packages which would be easy to use
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which version are you using of Maatwebsite/Excel ?

Comment: Did you checked this https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/blade/load-view.html ?

Comment: I've used version 3.1 but i was unable to bring the merge cell value to center

Comment: And which laravel version are you using ?

Comment: Laravel version 5.8.5